# How to get the selected cells count from a particular column of a DataGridView

Tags: datagridview, count, selected, datagridviewcolumn

I am looking for a way to get selected cells count from a specific DataGridView column.
I am able to retrieve all the selected cells from the DataGridView, but not from the specific column, with the help of [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx).

I tried using this piece of code, but it is returning selected cell count from entire grid.

```
SelectedCellsCount = dataGridView1.Columns[<<Column Name >>].DataGridView.SelectedCells.Count;
```

Can anyone please help me out to get this done ?

Thanks in advance.
Regards,
Vijay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found workaround to this. Now I am fetching all selected cells from the grid and depending upon the column index operating on it.